# Why ngfor paints the rows but not the data in it

Tags: angular

I'm having a problem with my first app made in Angular and .NET Core.
I made a backend in c# that returns an array like this:

```
[
  {
    "active":true,
    "codeEnabled":"CODE ENABLED",
    "codeDisabled":"CODE DISABLED",
    "codeSupervision":"CODE SUPERVISION",
    "name":"TEST 001",
    "messageEnabled":"MESSAGE ENABLED",
    "messageDisabled":"MESSAGE DISABLED",
    "messageSupervision":"MESSAGE SUPERVISION",
    "localization":"LOCALIZATION",
    "image":"",
    "actualState":"Actual state",
    "actualSuvervisionState":"supervision state",
    "dateLastSupervision":"2021-06-20T23:36:03.0000000Z",
    "id":1
  },
  {
    "active":true,
    "codeEnabled":"CODE ENABLED",
    "codeDisabled":"CODE DISABLED",
    "codeSupervision":"CODE SUPERVISION",
    "name":"TEST 002",
    "messageEnabled":"MESSAGE ENABLED",
    "messageDisabled":"MESSAGE DISABLED",
    "messageSupervision":"MESSAGE SUPERVISION",
    "localization":"LOCALIZATION",
    "image":"",
    "actualState":"Actual state",
    "actualSuvervisionState":"supervision state",
    "dateLastSupervision":"2021-06-20T23:43:50.8093498Z",
    "id":2
  }
  ...
]
```

Then in the front, that is made in Angular I made the model:

```js
export class Pokayoke {
  Id?: number;
  Active?: boolean;
  CodeEnabled?: string;
  CodeDisabled?: string;
  CodeSupervision?: string;
  Name?: string;
  MessageEnabled?: string;
  MessageDisabled?: string;
  MessageSupervision?: string;
  Localization?: string;
  Image?: Byte[];
  ActualState?: string;
  ActualSuvervisionState?: string;
  DateLastSupervision? : Date;
}
```

And a service that calls the API:

```
export class PokayokesService {
    
  listPokayokes!: Pokayoke[];
    
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  }
    
  getPokayokes()
  { 
    this.http.get("https://localhost/api/Pokayokes/GetList")
      .toPromise().then(data=>
      {
        this.listPokayokes = data as Pokayoke[];
        console.log(this.listPokayokes);
      });
  }
}
```

Note: I'm logging in just for debug, and the data seems correct:

[image: Console debug]

So my component will call this method on init:

```
export class PokayokesListComponent implements OnInit {
    
  constructor(public pokayokeService: PokayokesService) 
  {
    
  }
    
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pokayokeService.getPokayokes();
  }
    
}
```

And finally, the html, that will loop the list with an `ngFor`:

```
<table class="table table-sm">
  <tr *ngFor="let pokayoke of pokayokeService.listPokayokes; let i =index">
    <td>{{i}}</td>
    <td>{{pokayoke.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{pokayoke.Id }}</td>
    <td>{{pokayoke.Active }}</td>
    <td>{{pokayoke.CodeEnabled }}</td>
    <td>{{pokayoke.CodeDisabled }}</td>
    <td>{{pokayoke.CodeSupervision }}</td>
    <td>{{pokayoke.MessageEnabled }}</td>
    <td>{{pokayoke.MessageDisabled }}</td>
    <td>{{pokayoke.MessageSupervision }}</td>
    <td>{{pokayoke.Localization }}</td>
    <td>{{pokayoke.Image }}</td>
    <td>{{pokayoke.ActualState }}</td>
    <td>{{pokayoke.ActualSuvervisionState}}</td>
    <td>{{pokayoke.DateLastSupervision }}</td>        
  </tr>
</table>
```

At this point, I launch the application and I do not get errors in the console but the elements are not painted, however, the index is being painted.

[image: Result]

And I have no idea what can it be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Pokayoke` class' property names (**PascalCase**) don't match with your JSON property names (**camelCase**).

### SOLUTION

Change all the property names in `Pokayoke` class to **camelCase** and make sure both property names (in JSON and `Pokayoke` class) are the same will solve the issue.

> Pokayoke class

```js
export class Pokayoke {
  id?: number;
  active?: boolean;
  codeEnabled?: string;
  codeDisabled?: string;
  codeSupervision?: string;
  name?: string;
  messageEnabled?: string;
  messageDisabled?: string;
  messageSupervision?: string;
  localization?: string;
  image?: Byte[];
  actualState?: string;
  actualSuvervisionState?: string;
  dateLastSupervision?: Date;
}
```

> pokayoke.component.html

```
<table class="table table-sm">
    <tr *ngFor="let pokayoke of pokayokeService.listPokayokes; let i =index">
        <td>{{i}}</td>
        <td>{{pokayoke.name}}</td>
        <td>{{pokayoke.id }}</td>
        <td>{{pokayoke.active }}</td>
        <td>{{pokayoke.codeEnabled }}</td>
        <td>{{pokayoke.codeDisabled }}</td>
        <td>{{pokayoke.codeSupervision }}</td>
        <td>{{pokayoke.messageEnabled }}</td>
        <td>{{pokayoke.messageDisabled }}</td>
        <td>{{pokayoke.messageSupervision }}</td>
        <td>{{pokayoke.localization }}</td>
        <td>{{pokayoke.image }}</td>
        <td>{{pokayoke.actualState }}</td>
        <td>{{pokayoke.actualSuvervisionState}}</td>
        <td>{{pokayoke.dateLastSupervision }}</td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wtzxbj)